# Failed to execute child process "gnome-terminal" (too many levels of symbolic links)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

Just want to restore the Ubuntu to a previous state. Can't launch terminal because of the very problem I'm trying to fix by restoring it. Anyone know how to crack this nut?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: If your problem is being unable to launch a terminal then press ctrl-alt-f5.  That will drop you into a system terminal without gnome.

Answer (score 2):

This might be caused by python3.6/python3.7

In that case try this:

- Go to any folder you can find and right-click on it
- Select "open bash here"
- type: `sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-terminal`
- Modify the first line to: `#!/usr/bin/python`
- `ls /usr/bin/python*` and see if you have an old version, in my case (/usr/bin/python2.7)
- Delete python symlink if it already exists: `sudo rm /usr/bin/python`
- Create a symlink to this version: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python`

Now you can access your terminal again.

Comment: I ended up having to re-installing the whole system... that was a saga in it on itself...

Comment: This was the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Going to add my answer here as I ran into this as well, after updating python3 and screwing up the symbolic links via `sudo update-alternatives`, then removing the python symbolic links entirely. This completely broke `gnome-terminal` and `apt`.

I solved this issue by resetting the symbolic links to the original ones, via:

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

for `$python3`
and

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

for `$python`

This was for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, where my defaults python3 is python 3.6.9, it is likely to be different for future/past versions.

Answer (score -1):

1) Open XTerm

2) In XTerm run: **gnome-terminal**

3) You'll get something like this: "bash: Too many levels of symbolic links"

4) From Xterm, run: cd /usr/bin

5) Run: ll python*

Output: All the python folders installed in your computer

5.5) If you don't have any other versions of python, you might want to consider installing it now.

6) From Xterm, run: **sudo gedit gnome-terminal**

Output: That'll open the edit gnome-terminal

7) As I had python3 and python3.6 (two different folders with essentially the same content), I replaced python3 with python3.6 in the gnome-terminal edit file.

8) From Xterm, run again: gnome-terminal

9) You're welcome! lol